# AJAX post variable to PHP not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get a jQuery variable to a PHP variable. I have looked it up but can't find a solution. I have the following jQuery:

```
$('.eventRow').click(function(){

    var eventID = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax(
        {
        url: "index.php",
        type: "POST",

        data: {'phpEventId': eventID },
        success: function (result) {
                console.log('success');
        }
    });
```

When I console.log te "eventID" it correctly displays the number.

My PHP code is in the index.php. This is also where the .eventRow class is.

```
<?php

  $phpEventId = $_POST['phpEventId'];
  echo "<script>console.log('Nummer: ".$phpEventId."')</script>";
  print $phpEventId;

?>
```

However nothing happens. The console.log just displays: "Number: " Is there something wrong with the code? Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Could it be the problem that the index.php is already loaded before I click on the button? Because this php code is in the index.php and thus the $phpEventId is not yet set.

Comment: What happens if you add `console.log(eventID);` immediately after this line in your code: `var eventID = $(this).attr('id');`

Comment: It displays "21", which is the correct ID I need.

Comment: if you write var_dump($_POST); in php code , what is the results

Comment: Does seem to do something: array(0) { }

Comment: so your ajax doesn't send any data to php => at least your problem now from ajax side,,, it is time to send static data like data: {'phpEventId': 'test' },

Comment: That also displays array(0) { }

Comment: In addition to what @MohammadAlabed said, make sure you take a look at the network tab of your browser's dev tools to make sure the AJAX request is getting fired off correctly. You should see a POST request to the correct URL, with your data in the request.

Comment: I do not see that when I click the row.

Comment: Could it be the problem that the index.php is already loaded before I click on the button? Because this php code is in the index.php and thus the $phpEventId is not yet set.

Comment: Yes, of course. When you load index.php for the first time, the `$_POST` will return `array(0) { }`. However, when you click the button and the Ajax calls index.php, then `$_POST` should be returning 21. Can you confirm that?

Comment: No it still returns array(0) { } after clicking the button. Do I need to reload something first?

Comment: OK, check my updated answer and let me know the result. I cannot put it here in a comment.

Comment: I did! The result is commented under it

Answer (score 3):

In your Ajax, the `type: "POST"` is for jQuery prior to 1.9.0. If you're using the latest jQuery, then use `method: "POST"`.

If you're using the latest jQuery and you don't specify `method: "POST"`, then it defaults to `method: "GET"` and your PHP needs to capture it with `$_GET['phpEventId'];`.

After reading your update, let's try one thing. Change your PHP to return something meaningful to Ajax:

```
<?php
  $phpEventId = $_POST['phpEventId'];
  echo $phpEventId;
?>
```

Then try to capture the PHP response in your Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "index.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {'phpEventId': eventID },
    success: function (result) {
        alert("result: " + result);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have set it to method:post and are trying to get it with $_POST['$phpEventID']; but it still doesn't work

Comment: It displays my whole html, as well as the following: 
21array(1){
["phpEventId"]=>string(2) "21"}
string(2) "21"

Comment: I am using a query somewhere else that uses the phpEventId, and in the alertbox it is visible!

Comment: OK, well, perfect! So your PHP and Ajax are working properly. You just need to code your PHP code now, so it only responds to your Ajax and you should add code to validate the Ajax request and respond accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you have any idea how I can accomplish that? I am kind off new to this.

Comment: This is too broad and off topic, but basically you need to validate your request at least like this: `if ($_POST['phpEventId'] !== "")`. Other validation (e.g. the value must be an integer) depends on your requirements. And then only return (i.e. `echo`) what your Ajax needs, so you don't get a whole HTML page :-). Check this [simple example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp) for a start.

Comment: I tried to use your example but I can't manage to get it to work. Is there any way you can show me?

Comment: The code that I have in my answer is enough to make it work. You need to start with simple code like that and then add more code to it. Go step by step rather than trying to fix your whole existing code.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a part of your code, and the problem is somewhere else. In this context your code works just fine:

```
<div class="eventrow" id="1">This</div>
<div class="eventrow" id="2">That</div>
<script>
$('.eventRow').click(function(){

    var eventID = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax(
        {
        url: "index-1.php",
        type: "POST",

        data: {'phpEventId': eventID },
        success: function (result) {
                console.log('success: '+eventID);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

With the matching index-1.php:

```
<?php

  $phpEventId = $_POST['phpEventId'];
  echo "<script>console.log('Nummer: ".$phpEventId."')</script>";
  print $phpEventId;

?>
```

Not sure though why do you print javascript code (console.log) into an ajax response here...

Comment: Why do you use index-1.php? Because when I change it to that it says error 404: index-1.php not found

Comment: just wanted to underline, that you have to name your ajax respondant php the same way you specify the url in the ajax call and not something you copy from some sample ajax example

Answer (score 0):

**Error Is Visible Even Here**

According to WebZed round statistic report, this error was visible over 84% of web-developers.

> Failed to post data to PHP via JQuery while both frameworks and codes were updated.

**Possible Solutions Available Today**

1. Try using other methods for posting because JQUERY and AJAX libraries are not as efficient as shown in the surveys.
2. New frameworks are available which can do better with PHP.
3. Alternative method is to create a post request via $_GET method.
4. Regular HTML5 supports `<form></form>` try `method="post"`. *For security reasons try using enctype="" command.*

Try using React Native https://nativebase.io/